# Silent Hill: final boss with almost no ammo

Tags: silent-hill

So, I've been playing Silent Hill for the last two days and I finally got to the final boss, Samael (the one that attacks you with the blue lighting).

Somehow I managed to get there with just a few shotgun bullets and about 10 pistol bullets. I also have some rifle ammo but **don't** have the rifle itself. I can skip the boss attacks forever by running in circles, but I just don't have enough ammo to kill it.

I know about that trick that if you waste all the ammo just before you get to the boss, the game just skips the battle to the final cutscene. But the problem is that I have that extra rifle ammo but not the rifle, so I can't waste the ammo. Damn!

Is there any other trick to beat Samael when you have *almost* no ammo? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, in the end I just realized I had screwed up the game, so I restarted it all over again. Played almost four hours straight, this time picking up the damn rifle and saving all the ammo I could till the end, and finished it.

What an incredible game, it was well worth it.

> (By the way, the boss was actually Alessa, and I got the bad ending. Will try to get the good one next time -- hopefully I'll be able to finish it a little faster ;)).

Comment: I like your dedication :)

Answer (score 1):

If you shoot all of your bullets, even if you have some rifle ammo, after a while, Samael will die anyway!

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I knew about this trick, but I hadn't the rifle so I couldn't waste all the rifle ammo. :)

Comment: I believe @Ezio is trying to say is, if you spend all the ammo you have, Samael will die. Even if you can't use the rifle ammo because the lack of the rifle.